# Наша політика щодо посилань на піратський контент? / Our policy about links to a pirated content?

Tags: discussion, rules, admin-reference

Зрозуміло, що ми повинні не порушувати авторське право (не копіювати матеріали (за межами добросовісного використання) з сайтів не вільної ліцензії, вказувати автора/джерело при копіюванні вільних матеріалів чи матеріалів на умовах добросовісного використання тощо). Але яка буде наша політика щодо посилань на тих, хто самі порушують авторське право?

Наприклад, [отут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/289/4) людина публікує пряме посилання на скан книги, виданої 1985 року, тобто термін дії авторських прав, здається, ще не вийшов. Я, власне, не знаю ліцензійний стан цього скану — може, це грубе порушення, може, це сам правовласник опублікував. Важливий, власне, не цей конкретний випадок, а що робити з цього приводу в цілому.

Аспекти:

1. Можливо, це якось регулюється вищими правилами Stack Exchange?
2. Можливо, є якісь прецеденти в інших розділах (щось вирішували з цього приводу)?
3. Власне, не так легко зрозуміти, чи піратським є контент чи ні. Чи маємо ми це взагалі вирішувати? Чи несемо ми або Stack Exchange якусь відповідальність у випадку прямих посилань на піратські матеріали? Непрямих посилань на піратські матеріали?
4. Якщо припустити, що з точки зору правил Stack Exchange і законів України ми нічого не зобов'язані (наприклад, пришлють запит — тоді видалимо), яке буде соціальне рішення спільноти щодо цього? Чи проситимемо ми користувачів щось типу «будь ласка, не публікуйте посилання на піратський контент» просто з морального/іміджевого боку — чи просто нічого не робитимемо? Якщо проситимемо, в якій формі, що саме не рекомендується чи рекомендується?

---

It's obvious that we must not infringe copyright (don't copy materials (more than fair-use allows) from sites of non-free license, mention author/source when copying free materials or materials through fair-use, etc). But what would be out policy related to referring to those who break copyright themselves?

For example, [here](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/289/4), a user published a direct link to a scan of a book issued in 1985, i.e. it seems to be not in public domain yet. Actually, I don't know its license state — maybe, a copyright holder just scanned and published his own book, maybe, it's really pirated. I ask, actually, not about this specific case, but about our policy for such cases in general.

Aspects:

1. Maybe, some higher-level Stack Exchange rules regulate that?
2. Maybe, there are some precedents in other subsites (they already have some decision)?
3. Actually, it's not so easy to understand whether a content is pirated or no. Are we required to do it at all? Can we or Stack Exchange have some penalty for direct links to pirated content? For indirect links to pirated content?
4. Assuming we have not obligements according to Stack Exchange rules and Ukrainian laws (except to remove when a direct notice arrives), anyway, what's our own decision about this? Should we ask users not to publish links to seemingly-pirate content — or it's not our problem? If we should: in what form, what exactly is recommended/unrecommended to visitors?

Comment: Думаю, якщо це прямі посилання на завантаження книги (наприклад у форматі .pdf, .djvu чи тому подібне) - то вони є неприйнятними. Причина в тому, що такий лінк генерує безпосереднє отримання матеріалу і він жодним чином не показує сайт який надає цей матеріал. В такому випадку користувач немає жодних шансів ознайомитися з умовати отримання тієї чи іншої книги. Я дуже сподіваюсь, що для такого випадку існують базові правила Stack Exchange. Але якщо таких немає, то на мою думку, прямі посилання на завантаження точно не підходять.

Comment: Думаю, якщо файл можна безпомилково ідентифікувати під вільною ліцензією - тоді пряме посилання є допустимим. Але я всеодно не дуже підтримуватиму таку можливість. Причина в тому, що ймовірний варіант, коли користувач натискає посилання і одразу отримує файл (не сторінку, а таки файл). В такому випадку, можлива асоціація з тим, що файл поширюється через Stack Exchange, а не через сторонній сайт.

Comment: До речі, @Sasha, Ваш лінк веде "кудись не туди". Принаймні, це точно **не** рішення комітетів.

Comment: По перше, під `прямими посиланнями` я маю наувазі **не**  html-сторінку. По-друге, про «кудись не туди» я мав на увазі що назва Вашого посилання не відповідає тому, що відкрилося при кліку по тому посиланню.
І по-третє, я й не казав, що Ви сперечаєтесь.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53546/discussion-between-bohdan-kuts-and-sasha).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Policy on links either directly or indirectly to pirate content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/policy-on-links-either-directly-or-indirectly-to-pirate-content)

> Assuming it is pirated, it is not the place of Stack Exchange employees or moderators to take down those links unless a takedown notice is issued (see section 15 of the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)). And even then, that operation is performed by a Stack Exchange employee, not by a moderator or user.

To cut a long story short: we **should do nothing** about such links.

**Update with my personal opinion**: we should just ignore MOST of them. We should delete messages that we think is spam/advertisement or off topic.

I think after such cleanup only books that, unfortunately, cannot be legally obtained in electronic variant will be left. And I'll admit that I personally support scanning and distributing electronic variant of such books even though it is illegal. But if a link to legally obtainable electronic version exists, I'll be for replacing pirate link with that link.

I agree that links to html pages with links to content are preferred. (e. g. http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm in your sample)

I am **totally against** silent deletion of such links.

Anyone who feels that it is needed, can just write comment about that.

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer. Still, the question #4 about *our local opinion* remains open: If, say, you personally see somebody posting a link to, say, an obviously-pirate site — what would you do: just ignore it, or write smth like "Hey, please don't do that, this may damage reputation of our community (although not personally yours)", or just silently edit to remove it?

Comment: @Sasha I've added my personal opinion... But I've started to wonder whether it was correct decision... Now two upvotes seemingly support my opinion... Maybe it would be better to move my opinion to comments?..

Comment: I am agree with @KyryloYatsenko that we need to follow _Policy on links either directly or indirectly to pirate content_.

Comment: On a Q&A site, I don't think we'll have on-topic questions main idea of which is to share a pirate link. Most of the time I expect it would be "in this book [link] the following word/expression is used. is it correct?". Or the answer "here [link] it is said that it is a bad style". So it is more like "good-natured" prooflink to a resource than sharing a pirated content. A bit different is a situation with our future collection of links to educational resources, I bet someone could share a link to the library of books in ukrainian. But that's a different case which worth a separate discussion.

Comment: The last question just to clarify: If a link is not a book-link, but, for example, a surely-pirated film link (e.g. "at 45:14 the character *X* said *this* — what would Ukrainian say in such a situation?") — would your reaction to be mostly-same (i.e ignore)? (I don't criticize, I just ask to get sure I understood you correctly.)